# Would length of text affect React's rendering performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optimization, jsx

I was working on some optimization of my components.
I have a virtualized list and what I am trying to see is whether the length of text in `div` would affect React rendering performance or the number of sub HTML elements in `div` would affect the performance. I couldn't find good resources to compare those two cases. So, I would really appreciate if someone could give me some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a little common sense and say that in general, the more text (individual glyphs) you display, the lower your performance will be.

We can also easily guess that if you're trying to display the same quantity of text, more elements will always be slower than less, since they have to be processed recursively and there's less of a chance for using a single draw call to render said glyphs.